# Custom fields with spaces in Workfront issues

Tags: c#, workfront-api

Please, can you help me create/update items from custom fields that have space within their name?

We have a project with a custom field `Contact phone`. This field can be used correctly from the browser. https://github.com/Workfront/workfront-api-examples-csharp didn't help. I was able to add the data within the details of the issue. I would like to add it within the specific custom field (create/update).

```
var client = new AtTaskRestClient(_url); // from the example
...
var description = $"Contact phone: {item.ContactPhone}";
client.Create(ObjCode.ISSUE, new { name = item.Name,
    description = description,
    projectID = _projectID });
```

`client.Create` has an object as final parameter. We use an anonymous type that can't contain `"DE:Contact phone" = item.ContactPhone` within the constructor. How can we write this field?

Reading `DE:Contact phone` works correctly if we insert the value from the browser:

```
JToken issues = client.Search(ObjCode.ISSUE, new { projectID = _projectID });
foreach (var issue in issues["data"].Children()) {
    var name = issue.Value<string>("name"); // correct
    var id = issue.Value<string>("ID"); // correct
    var fields = client.Get(ObjCode.ISSUE, id, new[] { "description", "DE:Contact phone"}); // correct
```

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but Workfront will handle spaces in custom fields just fine. I'm not familiar with the C# implementation that you're using but I suspect that the issue lies in its handling of the space character. Also recall that Workfront does not do well handling the case where you attempt to set a custom field without first applying a custom form containing said field to the object. It's supposed to find the 'best' form and apply it but I've found that behavior to be erratic at best. Perhaps a multi-step operation in the order of create obj -> apply form -> set field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/Workfront/workfront-api-examples-csharp/blob/master/AtTaskRestExample/AtTaskRestClient.cs

```
public JToken Create(ObjCode objcode, object parameters) {
    VerifySignedIn();
    string[] p = parameterObjectToStringArray(parameters, "sessionID=" + SessionID);
    JToken json = client.DoPost(string.Format("/{0}", objcode), p);
    return json;
}
```

I wrote a new function CreateEx, that receives a string array

```
public JToken Create(ObjCode objcode, string[] parameters) {
    VerifySignedIn();
    JToken json = client.DoPost(string.Format("/{0}", objcode), parameters);
    return json;
}
```

It is accessed as follows:

```
var client = new AtTaskRestClient(_url); // from the example
...
string[] parameteres =
    {
        $"name={issueName}",
        $"description={description}",
        $"projectID={_projectID}",
        $"sessionID={client.SessionID}",
        $"DE:Contact phone={contactPhone}"
    };
client.CreateEx(ObjCode.ISSUE, parameteres);
```